# How to render a meteor page without referencing any internal libraries?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I need to render a Meteor page in iron-router without referencing any built in libraries. Essentially a standalone html page for displaying 500 error.

Comment: it depends on the context. you dont want a new route, correct? you can create a new template that holds the HTML you want, then call `this.render('template_name');`

Comment: What do you mean by "built-in libraries" or "internal libraries"? You can't load Meteor without loading jQuery, Underscore and several other libraries. And you can't load Iron Router without loading Meteor.